# how to implement select and deselect event in Kendo Angular multiselectBox

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

he guys,

I know Kendo for jquery has onSelect and deselct event out of the box,but kendo for angular has only onChange event,how i cant get those missing features(onSelect,deselect) from onChange event?

here is the component:

```
template: `
<div class="example-config">
  Current value: {{value | json}}
</div>
<div class="example-wrapper">
  <p>Favorite sport:</p>
  <kendo-multiselect  [data]="listItems" [(ngModel)]="value" (valueChange)="valueChange($event)"></kendo-multiselect>
</div>
```

here is my implementation:

```
export class AppComponent {
  public listItems: Array<string> = ['Baseball', 'Basketball', 'Cricket', 'Field Hockey', 'Football', 
 'Table Tennis', 'Tennis', 'Volleyball'];
  public value: any = [];
   public s :any=0;
   valueChange(e){
  console.log(e);

   }
```

i logged e to see if there is anything regarding select and deselect but seems there is not such a thing,any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a workaround to get selected & deselected from onChange events:

```
          public temp:any[]=[];
        public listItems: Array<string> = ['Baseball', 'Basketball', 'Cricket', 'Field Hockey', 'Football', 'Table Tennis', 'Tennis', 'Volleyball'];
        public value: any = [];

    valueChange(e){
      if(this.temp.length<e.length){
    console.log("seleted");
    this.temp.push(e.length);
      }
    else{
      console.log("Dseleted");
      if(this.temp.length!=0){this.temp.pop();this.temp.length}
    }
    console.log(e.length);
    }
```